# Submitting post in Laravel - A two minute digit could not be found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to submit a simple blog post. I pass the data using a request object as a DTO.

```
public function store(CreateBlogRequest $createBlogRequest)
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $post = $user->posts()->create([$createBlogRequest]);
}
```

I get the following error:

> "message": "Unexpected data found.\nUnexpected data found.\nUnexpected
>   data found.\nA two digit minute could not be found\nA two digit second
>   could not be found\nTrailing data"

However, when I pass the data as a standard array, it works perfectly.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $post = $user->posts()->create(['title' => $request->title, 'slug' => $request->slug, 'body' => $request->body]);
}
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; 

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Any idea what the issue is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass the request object (and you wrapped it in an array too). The `create()` method expects an associative array.

Instead, you can do what you did in the 2nd example. Or something like this:

```
$post = $user->posts()->create($createBlogRequest->input());
```

Or more explicit (and safer):

```
$post = $user->posts()->create($createBlogRequest->only(['title', 'slug', 'body']));
```

You might need to make the fields `$fillable` though.